# Using ReactDOMServer.renderToString with props

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

The whole purpose of using SSR is to hide the location data from the client. I want to use the location object that I get from the findLocation function and pass it to the react app. I try to pass it as a prop but it doesn't work well. I get an error in the browser console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'lon' of undefined at a (index.js:18)".
An example output from printing location in server.js and in app.js on the client :

```
[nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
SSR running on port 8080
{
  xid: 'W89710856',
  name: 'RBS',
  dist: 62.66979048,
  rate: 5,
  osm: 'way/89710856',
  kinds: 'historic_architecture,architecture,interesting_places,bank,banks,tourist_facilities,other_buildings_and_structures',
  point: { lon: -1.900748, lat: 52.481361 },
  cityDetails: {
    name: 'Birmingham',
    country: 'GB',
    lat: 52.48142,
    lon: -1.89983,
    population: 984333,
    timezone: 'Europe/London',
    status: 'OK'
  }
}
{
  xid: 'W89710856',
  name: 'RBS',
  dist: 62.66979048,
  rate: 5,
  osm: 'way/89710856',
  kinds: 'historic_architecture,architecture,interesting_places,bank,banks,tourist_facilities,other_buildings_and_structures',
  point: { lon: -1.900748, lat: 52.481361 },
  cityDetails: {
    name: 'Birmingham',
    country: 'GB',
    lat: 52.48142,
    lon: -1.89983,
    population: 984333,
    timezone: 'Europe/London',
    status: 'OK'
  }
} from the client
```

index.js for the server:

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
import App from "../src/App";
import { getCities } from "./external/cities.js";
import { useOpenTripMap } from "./external/openTripMap.js";
 
const PORT = 8080;
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
 
const citiesArray = getCities();
const radius = 1000;
// locations results limit
const limit = 20;
 
const findLocation = async () => {
  try {
    const cities = await citiesArray;
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length);
    const city = await useOpenTripMap(
      "geoname",
      encodeURI("name=" + cities[random].name)
    );
    const locations = await useOpenTripMap(
      "radius",
      encodeURI(
        `radius=${radius}&limit=${limit}&lon=${city.lon}&lat=${city.lat}&format=json`
      )
    );
    if (!Array.isArray(locations) || !locations.length) {
      return findLocation();
    }
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length);
    return locations[random].name
      ? {
          ...locations[random],
          cityDetails: { ...city },
        }
      : findLocation();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
 
const serverRenderer = (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("./build/index.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send("An error occurred");
    }
    findLocation()
      .then((location) => {
        console.log(location); / a valid object with a point property
        return res.send(
          data.replace(
            '<div id="root"></div>',
            `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
              <App location={location} />
            )}</div>`
          )
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  });
};
router.use("^/$", serverRenderer);
 
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")));
 
app.use(router);
 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SSR running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

index.js for the react app:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

const mountElement = document.getElementById("root");
const reactMountFn =
  mountElement?.childElementCount === 0 ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate;
reactMountFn(<App />, mountElement);
```

app.js in src folder in the react app:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Map from "./components/map";

function App({ location }) {
  console.log(location, "from the client");
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Map point={location?.point} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you log out `cities` and `city` after initializing them, are they both defined?

Comment: @ZacAnger Yes. I get an array of cities objects from "cities" and a city object from "city".

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Map` component is giving you the error since you don't provide location object to the `App` component (and Map's `point` prop is hence undefined) on the client side:

```
// index.js
...

reactMountFn(<App />, mountElement); // <-- App's location prop is undefined
```

As a quick fix I would do the following:

```
function App({ location }) {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Map point={location ? location.point : {}} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

React will probably give you a warning about mismatches between client and server markups. In that case you will need to inject server side variables (such as `location` object) in result HTML and use them on the client side. Please, refer to [this manual](https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering#inject-initial-component-html-and-state) for more details.

For example, on the server side index.js:

```
...

return res.send(
  data.replace(
    '<div id="root"></div>',
    `<script>window.__LOCATION__=${JSON.stringify(location)}</script>
    <div id="root">
      ${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <App location={location} />
      )}
    </div>`
  )
);
...
```

On the client side index.js:

```
// Get the location from a global variable injected into the server generated HTML
const location = JSON.parse(window.__LOCATION__);
reactMountFn(<App location={location} />, mountElement);
```

Comment: I don't get any errors now but I can't use the location's point from the server. I don't use redux so I don't understand how to use that link to solve the issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use redux or not. You can inject any variable into your template using the same principle. Added a short example to my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Ok I got it, but now it makes no sense cause the purpose was to hide the location data from the client, and now it's visible.

Comment: Then you shouldn't render components that consume the location data. Otherwise you have to pass the location from the server side.

Comment: How to do that? That's the whole point of what i'm trying to do from the beginning, get the map with the location calculated in the server without exposing it to the client.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer. You cannot "hide" the location data from the client and get Map component that depends on that data rendered somehow.

Comment: I'm trying to create a game like Geo Guesser, when the player has to guess the location. how would you implement that?

Comment: I have never played Geo Guesser, so it may be irrelevant, but whenever player submits the answer with a guessed location I would make some API call to an endpoint that checks whether player's answer is right or wrong.

Comment: Yes but he could just look at the answer in the developer tools because the location object is visible from the client browser. How would you solve it?

Comment: No, let me clarify: in this approach you don't pass the location object to the client beforehand. Instead, you make a request to a dedicated API endpoint to check if player's guess is correct. In this case there is no way to know the right location before player gives an answer.

Comment: Yes, but you have to pass the location beforehand in order to load the map for this location, that's the problem.

Comment: from the mapbox docs: At the heart of Mapbox GL JS is client-side rendering. In web apps using Mapbox GL JS, maps are rendered dynamically by combining vector tiles with style rules using JavaScript and WebGL